How to underline several empty lines
I need 3 lines to be underlined and doesn't contain text. I tried:
\usepackage{ulem}
\uline{\hfill \\ \hfill \\ \hfill}

But it doesn't output more than one empty line.

See if the following works for you:
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\uline{~\hfill}

\uline{~\hfill}

\uline{~\hfill}
\end{document}


If your lines don't contain text, you could use \hrulefill:
\documentclass{article}
    
\begin{document}

test

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent\hrulefill

test

\end{document}

Or \hrules:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test
\vskip\baselineskip
\hrule
\vskip\baselineskip
\hrule
\vskip\baselineskip
\hrule
\vskip\baselineskip
test

\end{document}


+1 I like low-level solutions! But for the non-initiated I would add the info that no interline glue is added before/after \hrule, hence the need for the \vskips.
